# Persistent Bar is Crashing with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, navbar

I want to make a navbar in footer of my codeigniter web project. I found a problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
```

That stylesheet is crashing with the sliding menu. It make my searching input messed up too.
[image]

When i choose the account it will display something like this. The filling inside the sliding menu put above the toolbar. And the slider didn't work anymore.
[image]

But when i'm reload the account page it will display the better page although the searching still messed up.

[image]

I don't know what to do. It would be great if u can help me. Thank you . .

View Home

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>home</title>
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Custom Theme files -->
        <!--theme-style-->
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />  
        <!--//theme-style-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Food shop Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template, 
        Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" />
        <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
        <!--fonts-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!--//fonts-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/move-top.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/easing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
                });
            });
        </script>
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/imgslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/slideout.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.wmuSlider.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.wmuGallery.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"> 
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "[data-role='navbar']" ).navbar();
                $( "[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']" ).toolbar();
            });
            // Update the contents of the toolbars
            $( document ).on( "pagecontainershow", function() {
                // Each of the four pages in this demo has a data-title attribute
                // which value is equal to the text of the nav button
                // For example, on first page: <div data-role="page" data-title="Info">
                var current = $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "title" );
                // Change the heading
                $( "[data-role='header'] h1" ).text( current );
                // Remove active class from nav buttons
                $( "[data-role='navbar'] a.ui-btn-active" ).removeClass( "ui-btn-active" );
                // Add active class to current nav button
                $( "[data-role='navbar'] a" ).each(function() {
                    if ( $( this ).text() === current ) {
                        $( this ).addClass( "ui-btn-active" );
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>   

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="menu">
            <h1 style="color:white">Menu</h1>
            <hr style="color:white;">
            <ul>

                <?php if($tipeUser=="user"){?>
                    <li><h4 style="color:white">Welcome <?php echo $nama;?></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" style="color:white">Home</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/my_voucher/0" style="color:white">My Voucher</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/my_profile" style="color:white">Profile</a></h4></li> 
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/logout" style="color:white">Logout</a></h4></li>
                    <?php } else if($tipeUser=="restoran"){ ?>

                    <li><h4 style="color:white">Welcome <?php echo $nama;?></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" style="color:white">Home</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/dashboard" style="color:white">Dashboard</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/voucher_management" style="color:white">Voucher Management</a></h4></li>
                    <!-- <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/redeem_voucher" style="color:white">Reedem Voucher</a></h4></li> -->
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/logout" style="color:white">Logout</a></h4></li>
                    <?php } else if($tipeUser==""){  ?>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" style="color:white">Home</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/login" style="color:white">Login / Register</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/list_voucher" style="color:white">Voucher</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/list_restoran" style="color:white">Restaurants</a></h4></li>
                        <?php
                        if($data_kategori->num_rows()>0)
                        {
                            foreach ($data_kategori->result() as $rows)
                            { ?>

                                <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/Type/<?php echo $rows->id_jenis_makanan; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $url_image;?>category/<?php echo $rows->id_jenis_makanan; ?>/<?php echo $rows->img_jenis_makanan; ?>" width="100%" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a></h4></li>

                        <?php } } ?>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/faq" style="color:white">Faq</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/blog" style="color:white">Blog</a></h4></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <main id="panel">
            <header><!--header-->
                <div class="header-in" >
                    <div class="container">
                        <!---->
                        <div class="header-bottom" >

                            <div class="col-xs-1">
                                <button class="toggle-button"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-9">
                                <?php echo form_open('home_controller/search_bar');?>
                                <div class="search">
                                    <form>
                                        <input type="text" id= "input-keyword" name="input-keyword" placeholder="Search ..." value="<?php echo set_value('input-keyword')?>" >
                                        <input type="submit" value="">  
                                    </form><?php echo form_close(); ?> 
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <!---->

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!---->
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-role="content">
                    <?php 
                        if($dataSliderVoucher->num_rows()>0)
                        { ?>  
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <?php 
                                $i = 1;
                                foreach ($dataSliderVoucher->result() as $rowsSliderVoucher)
                                { 
                                    if($i==1)
                                    {
                                    ?>

                                    <div class="item active">
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/Details/<?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->id_restoran?>"><center><img src="<?php echo $url_image;?>restaurant/<?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->id_restoran?>/deals/<?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->gambar_voucher?>" height="200em" class="img-responsive" alt=""></center></a>
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            <h3><?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->nama_voucher?></h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php }
                                    else
                                    { ?>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/Details/<?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->id_restoran?>"><center><img src="<?php echo $url_image;?>restaurant/<?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->id_restoran?>/deals/<?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->gambar_voucher?>" height="200em" class="img-responsive" alt=""></center></a>
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            <h3><?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->nama_voucher?></h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } 
                                $i++;} ?>
                        </div>

                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <!---->
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="specials">
                            <h2>Latest Deals</h2>
                            <?php if($dataLastDeals->num_rows()>0)
                                {
                                    foreach ($dataLastDeals->result() as $rowsLastDeals)
                                    { ?>

                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <!-- Product -->


                                            <!-- Product Title -->


                                                <!--<h3 style="font-size: 6vw;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $rowsLastDeals->nama_restoran?></h3>-->
                                                <!--<h3 style="font-size: 4vw;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $rowsLastDeals->nama_voucher;?></h3>-->
                                                <!--<h3 style="font-size: 4vw;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">Valid until : <?php $date=date_create($rowsLastDeals->masa_berlaku); echo date_format($date, "d-M-Y"); ?></h3>-->
                                                <!--
                                                    <?php 
                                                    if($rowsLastDeals->sisa_voucher > 0) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <h4  style="font-size: 3vw;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;" align="center">AVAILABLE (<?php echo $rowsLastDeals->sisa_voucher. ' Voucher'?> from <?php echo $rowsLastDeals->jumlah_voucher. ' Voucher'?>)</h4>
                                                    <?php
                                                    }
                                                    else{ ?>
                                                    <h4 align="center" style="color:red; font-size: 3vw;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">NOT AVAILABLE</h4>
                                                    <?php }
                                                ?>-->

                                            <!-- Add to Cart Button -->
                                            <?php if($tipeUser=="user" || $tipeUser==""){ ?>
                                                <div class="actions">
                                                    <?php 
                                                        if($rowsLastDeals->sisa_voucher > 0) {
                                                        ?>
                                                        <center>
                                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/GetVoucher/<?php echo $rowsLastDeals->id_voucher;?>">
                                                            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>.././img/restaurant/<?php echo $rowsLastDeals->id_restoran;?>/deals/<?php echo $rowsLastDeals->gambar_voucher;?>" class="img-responsive-search" alt="" style="object-fit: fill;height: 90px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                                                        </a></center>
                                                        <?php
                                                        }
                                                        else{ ?>
                                                        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>.././img/restaurant/<?php echo $rowsLastDeals->id_restoran;?>/deals/<?php echo $rowsLastDeals->gambar_voucher;?>" class="img-responsive-search" alt="" style="object-fit: fill;height: 90px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                                                        <!--<center><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/GetVoucher/<?php echo $rowsLastDeals->id_voucher;?>" disabled class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i>Get Voucher</a></center><br>-->
                                                        <?php }
                                                    ?>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php } ?>


                                        <!-- End Product -->
                                    </div>
                                <?php }} ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </header>
        </main>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" data-transition="pop">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/login" data-transition="pop">Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/list_voucher">Voucher</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/faq">Faq</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/blog">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /footer -->  

    <?php if($this->session->flashdata('message')) :     
    echo "<script>alert('". $this->session->flashdata('message')."')</script>";
    endif; ?>
</body>



<script>


    var slideout = new Slideout({
        'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
        'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
        'padding': 190,
        'tolerance': 70
    });

    // Toggle button
    document.querySelector('.toggle-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        slideout.toggle();
    });
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
    if( userAgent.match( /iPad/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPhone/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPod/i ) )
    {
        slideout.disableTouch();

    }

    // auto close
    slideout.on('open', function() {
        $( "#panel" ).click(function() {
            return false; 
        });
        $( "#panel" ).click(function() {
            slideout.close();
        });
    });

    slideout.on('close', function() {
        $( "#panel" ).unbind('click');
    });


    </script>

    <script>
    $('.gallery').wmuSlider(); 

    </script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
        $( "[data-role='navbar']" ).navbar();
        $( "[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']" ).toolbar();
    });
    // Update the contents of the toolbars
    $( document ).on( "pagecontainershow", function() {
        // Each of the four pages in this demo has a data-title attribute
        // which value is equal to the text of the nav button
        // For example, on first page: <div data-role="page" data-title="Info">
        var current = $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "title" );
        // Change the heading
        $( "[data-role='header'] h1" ).text( current );
        // Remove active class from nav buttons
        $( "[data-role='navbar'] a.ui-btn-active" ).removeClass( "ui-btn-active" );
        // Add active class to current nav button
        $( "[data-role='navbar'] a" ).each(function() {
            if ( $( this ).text() === current ) {
                $( this ).addClass( "ui-btn-active" );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you set your base url in config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';`

Comment: yes, i already save it @wolfgang1983